# how to use calculation from one cell to direct to to cells above

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I currently have a macro set up to give me the furthest right “X” cell whereby excel tells me its column number and this is put into a cell.

I would like to know how to use the result of this cell to have excel count along a specified row, using the given number and display the information in this cell (as a date).

[image: example sheet screenshot]

In the image example I have set excel R1C1 formatting. The number at 15,15 represents the X at 13,6 which is giving 13 as it is in the 13th column. I would like to have excel automatically work out that in 13,1 is the date that that refers to the furthest right X, and then output this date in the cell labelled DATE.

I would then have to use the same method for other rows but the hope is that I can apply the same outcome if anyone is able to help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want the resulting formula to be 5 columns right of A4?? Or do you want to count cells in a range from A4 to 5 columns to the right? You seem confused yourself about E4 or F4. Please edit your question. Provide a screenshot or some sample data and point to the cells that you want to calculate or where you want to see a result. Don't do that in a comment. Edit your question.

Comment: If that can help write in cell B4: `=IF($A4=COLUMN(B4),"MyInfo";"")` then stretch all the way to the right. This will have the text 'MyInfo' written only in the cell E4 if A4 is equal to 5. Otherwise I also recommend to follow what @teylyn recommends.

Comment: Thanks @teylyn, I have edited the question so hopefully it is clearer

Comment: Do you need the R1C1 setting for other calculation? I think the normal A1 is better for formula to make absolute reference easier and for the place you write the formula

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably to use indirect:

`=INDIRECT("R1C"&R15C15)`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove the merged cells you can increase the row Height and column Width instead, Your Data will become 6 rows only and 16 columns.
In the cell to in column 16, Row 10 (16,10) write the following Formula:

```
=INDEX(R[-9]C[-14]:R[-9]C,1,MAX(IF(R[-6]C[-14]:R[-6]C="X",COLUMN(R[-6]C[-14]:R[-6]C),0)-1))
```

Array Formula you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time
this formula is for the number 3 in your Data
The formula find the Max column corresponding at the Last X in the Row
The Date being written oldest to nearest
Max will find the nearest Date corresponding to X in the row
Index will return the Date in the first Row
You have to change it to correspond to the next rows

[image]

For normal reference A1 you can use:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$P$1,1,MAX(IF($B$4:$P$4="X",COLUMN($B$4:$P$4),0)-1))
```

B1:P1 the Date Row
B4:P4 the Row where you have X
And of course Array Formula you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time